# How to push notification if data is from API?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am creating an app where in it requires to push notifications regarding the updated payment remittances of the user. How can I send the notification to the user when my backend is done dumping the latest payment remittances. What will be the trigger from the API to send notification to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You should use APNS for delivery push-notification for iOS device.
For more info see  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html